# What is the this return type in scala?

Tags: scala

I have a trait like this:

```scala
trait MyBag[A]{
    def add(elem: A): This
}
```

What is the `:This` return type? Does this mean the `add` function returns an instance of MyBag?

Comment: Do you mean `this.type`? Could you provide rest of the code because this does not compile.

Comment: `This` can be a type defined in your project. For example `trait MyBag[A]{
    type This;
    def add(elem: A): This
}`. For example in Slick https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/master/slick/src/main/scala/slick/ast/Node.scala#L13

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`This` is just the name of a type that is defined somewhere else that you are not showing us. The compiler doesn't speak English, it doesn't care whether a type is named `This` or `Foo` or `Fgjbgjzdz55437365643w`.